# Reset Firebase cache

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, persistence, firebase-realtime-database

While developing with Firebase, I manually added a data record in the console but forgot one entry, which caused the app to crash. I've corrected the problem in the console but, because I was using Firebase's data persistence, the original data error persists, causing the crash again.  If I switch the persistence off, everything is fine but the cached store isn't being updated.  Has anyone had this problem and found a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced this issue, and have lost sleep over the thought of users being trapped in an endless crash-on-start-up loop.

As suggested, the opportunity for the issue to arise is created in the time window between the start up of an app and the subsequent arrival of cache updates from the Firebase server.  If data is read from the cache during this time window, and then, if the data happens to be missing an expected value, and then, if the app uses the data in a way that assumes the data will not be nil, the app crashes.  If the app crashes before the cache updates, the cache will never have the chance to update, and the user will be trapped in an endless loop (absent wiping the app's data from the device's memory).

Thus far, I've dealt with the issue by more strenuously guarding against the possibility of nil values in code that is called during start up.  If nil is checked and inconveniently found, then, depending upon the situation, either (1) if possible and if it will not lead to further data corruption, the app substitutes an appropriate value in place of nil, or otherwise (2) the app goes into a wait mode for a couple of seconds, and then initiates a fresh read from the problem node, and then reattempts the start-up routine.

Perhaps the moral of the story is never assume that a value is non-nil or otherwise within an expected range.  Either validate the value upon receipt or check the value at the time of intended use or both, and then handle errors accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The cache should update automatically. Since this happens in a background thread without, while it invokes your code on the main thread, I'd expect it to update the disk cache even if you application code crashes.

But if that doesn't happen, the fastest way to get back in a good state is to clear the app data for you application or to completely uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I managed to solve the problem by making the db call conditional on getting the correct data. This meant nothing happened at first when the cache was enabled. After an additional restart, I could get the cache to synch again. It seems Firebase is asynchronously refreshing the cache but this was happening slower than my code was starting. Is there something I can add to my code to protect against this kind of problem?  I'm thinking of a possible solution that switches caching off in the event of a crash and enables persistence once the db has synched.